# Sort bullit list by li class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to sort an excisting ul li list based on class name end creat new bullit lists for each class

now:

```
    <ul>
     <li class="a"></li>
     <li class="a"></li>
     <li class="b"></li>
     <li class="b"></li>
     <li class="b"></li>
     <li class="c"></li>
    </ul>
```

must be converted to:

```
<ul>
<li class="a"></li>
<li class="a"></li>
</ul>

<ul>
<li class="b"></li>
<li class="b"></li>
<li class="b"></li>
</ul>

<ul>
<li class="c"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `.unwrap()` and `.wrapAll()`:

```
 $('ul li').unwrap();
 $('.a').wrapAll('<ul></ul>')
 $('.b').wrapAll('<ul></ul>')
 $('.c').wrapAll('<ul></ul>')
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5b5Em/2/)**

Comment: This produces invalid HTML: `<ul><ul>...</ul></ul>`

Comment: @RGraham:no it is not. See the fiddle.

Comment: I am checking it? There is no `li` in between the nested lists - http://tinypic.com/r/fyiter/8

Comment: many thanx this works for me:D, because every item a b and c needs a different class

Answer (score 4):

You can use **[.unwrap()](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/)** and **[.wrapAll()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/)**:

```
$(function(){
    $('ul li').unwrap();
    var classes = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
    for (i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
        $('li.' + classes[i]).wrapAll('<ul></ul>');
    }
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/F2bp6/1/)**

Comment: +1. I did used your solution, changed the for loop to use map. Hopefully not against the rules.

Comment: Not at all. Good solution +1 from me too :-)

Answer (score 4):

Using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) (based on [Felix' solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22761530/sort-bullit-list-by-li-class/22761621#22761621)):

```
$(function(){
    $('ul li').unwrap();
    ['a', 'b', 'c'].map(function(x) {$('li.' + x).wrapAll('<ul></ul>')});   
});
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F2bp6/3/)

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you regardless of the classes in the li, i.e you don't have to know the classes ahead:

```
$(function () {
    var classes = new Array();
    var i = 0;
    $("li").each(function () {
        var currentClass = $(this).attr('class');
        if (classes.indexOf(currentClass) < 0) {
            classes[i] = currentClass ;
            i++;
        }
    });
    $('ul li').unwrap();
    for (i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
        $("." + classes[i]).wrapAll('<ul></ul>');
    }
});
```

[Live example here](http://jsfiddle.net/5RLgF/)